# how to sort numerically in hadoop's shuffle/sort phase?

Tags: sorting, hadoop

The data looks like this, first field is a number,

```
3 ...
1 ...
2 ...
11 ...
```

And I want to sort these lines according to the first field numerically instead of alphabetically, which means after sorting it should look like this,

```
1 ...
2 ...
3 ...
11 ...
```

But hadoop keeps giving me this,

```
1 ...
11 ...
2 ...
3 ...
```

How do correct it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming you are using **Hadoop Streaming**, you need to use the **KeyFieldBasedComparator** class.

1. -D mapred.output.key.comparator.class=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedComparator should be added to streaming command
2. You need to provide type of sorting required using mapred.text.key.comparator.options. Some useful ones are -n : numeric sort, -r : reverse sort

**EXAMPLE** :

Create an identity mapper and reducer with the following code

This is the **mapper.py** & **reducer.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:    
    print "%s" % (line.strip())
```

This is the **input.txt**

```
1
11
2
20
7
3
40
```

This is the **Streaming** command

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar 
-D mapred.output.key.comparator.class=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedComparator 
-D  mapred.text.key.comparator.options=-n 
-input /user/input.txt 
-output /user/output.txt 
-file ~/mapper.py 
-mapper ~/mapper.py 
-file ~/reducer.py 
-reducer ~/reducer.py
```

And you will get the required output

```
1   
2   
3   
7   
11  
20  
40
```

**NOTE** :

1. I have used a simple one key input. If however you have multiple keys and/or partitions, you will have to edit mapred.text.key.comparator.options as needed. Since I do not know your use case , my example is limited to this
2. Identity mapper is needed since you will need atleast one mapper for a MR job to run.
3. Identity reducer is needed since shuffle/sort phase will not work if it is a pure map only job.

Comment: is it possible to change the sort order as well?

Comment: Thank you for saving my life.

Answer (score 7):

Hadoop's default comparator compares your keys based on the `Writable` type (more precisely `WritableComparable`)  you use. If you are dealing with `IntWritable` or `LongWritable` then it will sort them *numerically*.

I assume you are using `Text` in your example therefore you'll end up having *natural sort order*.

In special cases, however, you can also write your own comparator.
E.g: *for testing purposes only*, here's a quick sample how to change the sort order of Text keys: this will treat them as integers and will produce numerical sort order:

```
public class MyComparator extends WritableComparator {

        public MyComparator() {
            super(Text.class);
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {

            try {

                String v1 = Text.decode(b1, s1, l1);
                String v2 = Text.decode(b2, s2, l2);

                int v1Int = Integer.valueOf(v1.trim());
                int v2Int = Integer.valueOf(v2.trim());

                return (v1Int < v2Int) ? -1 : ((v1Int > v2Int) ? 1 : 0);

            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the jobrunner class set:

```
Job job = new Job();
...
job.setSortComparatorClass(MyComparator.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I donot write `java`.

Comment: @Alcott : for `Hadoop-streaming` refer to this: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/streaming.html#Hadoop+Comparator+Class

Answer (score 1):

For streaming with order Hadoop (which may use `-jobconf` instead of `-D` for configuration), you can sort by key:

```
-jobconf stream.num.map.output.key.fields=2\
-jobconf mapreduce.partition.keycomparator.options="-k2,2nr"\
-jobconf mapred.output.key.comparator.class=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedComparator
```

By `stream.num.map.output.key.fields`, 1st and 2nd columns are `key 1` and `key 2`.

`mapreduce.partition.keycomparator.options="-k2,2nr"` means sorting in reverse order by using 2nd key (from 2nd to 2nd keys) as numeric value.

It is pretty much like Linux `sort` command!