# Force integer sort in Hadoop on Elastic Map Reduce (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I am using a map reducer on Hadoop on Elastic Map Reduce (on AWS) but it is sorting it as a string, I want to do integer sorting. How to do it ? I want to take the key as integer and do integer sorting on the key.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend pre-pending (or padding) the integer with leading zeros so that you can get Hadoop (or EMR) to do lexographical sorting. Hadoop doesn't support integer based sorting - its simply lexographic sorting.

For example, if these are your keys:

```
1
15
168
1900
```

You should output them like this in your mapper:

```
0001
0015
0168
1900
```

so that Hadoop can correctly sort them.

Answer (score 0):

This related question's answers could be used without modifying the data: [how to sort numerically in hadoop's shuffle/sort phase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331722/how-to-sort-numerically-in-hadoops-shuffle-sort-phase)